# cannot read camera capture with opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-capture

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print(ret)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is the example code for opening the webcam. I was able to run this a few months ago without any problem and the webcam is working fine with QuickTime.

But now, cap.read() always returns False, no matter what.
I was trying with different numbers at VideoCapture() from -1 to 3, none of them working

I am pretty sure its not the code's fault. But there must be something messed up with the environment.
Currently I am using python 3.5, open-cv 3.1.0
this python interpreter is /usr/local/Cellar/python3/...

do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

rebuilding and installing opencv fixed it.